# Center Vis.js timeline on current date on open

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have a VisJS timeline ranging from January 2017-2018. The timeline opens centered on a three month range mid-year, but I would like it to open every time centered at the current time.

```
min: new Date(2017, 1, 5),           // lower limit of visible range
max: new Date(2018, 1, 11),          // upper limit of visible range
zoomMin: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,        // one day in milliseconds
zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*31*3,   // three months in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 6):

You may try with something like this (`timeline.setWindow()`):

```
const todayStart = new Date();
todayStart.setHours(8, 0, 0, 0);
const todayEnd = new Date();
todayEnd.setHours(18, 0, 0, 0);

console.log(todayStart, ':', todayEnd);
setTimeout(_ => {
  this.timeline.setWindow(todayStart, todayEnd, { animation: true });
});
```

or better with the `moveTo`

```
  this.timeline.moveTo(new Date());//or
  this.timeline.moveTo(new Date(), { animation: true });//or
  this.timeline.moveTo(new Date(), { animation: true }, (props) => {
    console.log("movedTo", props);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use start and end on [Configuration Options](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options) to achieve what you want.

```
var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59,999)+1);

var options = {
    in: new Date(2018, 1, 5), 
    max: new Date(2019, 1, 11),    
    zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*31*3, 
    start:today,
    end:tomorrow
};
```

I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/betim-beja/pen/MBzdgb) implementation of this specific solution.